# Java Observer/Observable

Tags: java, observable

I have to create a code for an observable and an observer. Each observer has its own "update" method as you already know.

In my observable code, i used the "notifyObservers" method. Its parameter is a string array containing infos about my projects ( command number, name of the hamburger, name of the drink,etc..).

I still have an error in my update method in my observer and I don't know where it comes from. Its two parameters are the observable and the string array containing the infos I already specified.

here is my code

```
public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1)
{
    if (!(arg0 instanceof BDCommande))
        System.out.println("Objet émetteur inconnu\n");
    if (arg1 instanceof String[]) {
        String[] labels = new String[5];
        labels = (String[]) arg1;
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Type de message inconnu");
    int num = Integer.parseInt(labels[0]);
}
```

An error is detected in the last line of the method, labels[0] seems to not be recognized.

If someone can help me here, it's be cool.
Thanks ! ( and sorry for my poor english I'm french )

Comment: The variable `labels` only exists inside the `{}` block in which it is created. What is `labels` supposed to be if `arg1` is not an instance of `String[]` ?

Comment: Well it was a bit silly of me ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: #JustForRecords: java Observable is deprecated in Java 10. Better start moving towards RxJava Observables

Answer (score 0):

you error come from your definition of `labels`. just change it to

```
public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1)
{
    String[] labels = new String[5];
    if (!(arg0 instanceof BDCommande))
        System.out.println("Objet émetteur inconnu\n");
    if (arg1 instanceof String[]) {
      //  String[] labels = new String[5];
        labels = (String[]) arg1;
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Type de message inconnu");
    int num = Integer.parseInt(labels[0]);
}
```

And also make sure your `labels` are really initialized.  Because if `(arg1 instanceof String[])` is `false`, then you'll get a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the `labels` variable inside your if statement, which means that the scope of it is restricted to that `if` block.  If you need access to it, you should declare it outside, like so:

```
public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
   String[] labels = new String[5];
   if (!(arg0 instanceof BDCommande)) {
      System.out.println("Objet émetteur inconnu\n");
   }
   if (arg1 instanceof String[]) {
      labels = (String[]) arg1;
   }
   else {
      System.out.println("Type de message inconnu");
   }
   int num = Integer.parseInt(labels[0]);
}
```